# Regular expression to get span tag

Tags: regex

May I know what is the regular expression rule for matching html tag

```
<span id="id1" class="class1" attribute="attribute1">Test</span>
```

that matches the tag SPAN regardless the property in it.

My existing rule is this, but not working.

```
/(<span [^>]*>)>/s
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

David, the reason `(<span [^>]*>)>` is that you have a small typo.

You see, that expression tries to match **two** closing `>`: look closely at the end `>)>`. For instance, it would match `<span hey there>>` but not `<span hey there>`

To match the opening span, make sure you only have one `>`.

With all the disclaimers about using regex to match html, this regex will do:

```
<span[^>]*>
```

If you sometimes expect `SPAN`, make sure to make it case-insensitive.

**Only if you have time: an additional flourish**

In a comment, @DavidEhrmann points out that the regex above will match `<spanner>`. If you want to make him happy and ensure that if the span is more than just `<span>` it always contains a space after `span`, you can use:

```
<span(?: [^>]*)?>
```

However, in my view, that is an unnecessary flourish. When we parse html with regex, we always know that we are using a crude tool, and we rely on the input to be fairly well-formed. For instance, with the revised regex above, there are still a million ways that we can match improper html, for instance: `<span classification>`

What to do? Nothing. Know your tools, know what they can do, know the risks, and decide when the situation warrants regex and when it warrants a DOM parser.

Comment: That also matches <spanner> (not that it's a real tag).

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Sure, I know that. Within the context of using regex to match html, which davidlee is trying to do, I am trying to help fix his expression. IMO trying to make a regex for a `<span...>` more specific would be error-fraught (what do we want to allow: classes? ids? styles?)

Comment: @DavidEhrmann To let you rest at ease, added an option to avoid `<spanner>`, should davidlee also care. :) Cheers.

Comment: Obligatory link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at here [**Regex for Html Tags**](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm)

Try This

```
<span[^>]*>[\s\S]+<\/span>
```

**[Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/t2I81chanE)**

---

O/ P:

[image]

Comment: Does not work http://rubular.com/r/F0WdIAOpC1 I would -1...except that is an awesome website...thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
/<span[^>]*>[^>]*<\/span>/
```

Comment: Fails if span contains internal tags.